# C pointer initialization differences

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to C and have some questions about the pointer.

Question 1 What`s differences b/w the following two? Which way is better to initialize a pointer and why?

```
int *p=NULL;
int *p;
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
   char *s = "hello";
   printf("%p\t%p",s);
   //printf("%p\t%p",&s) it will give me unpredictable result every time
   //printf("%p\t%p",(void *)&s) it will be fine
   //Question3: why?
}
```

Question 2: I try to google what is `%p` doing. According to my reading, it is supposed to print the pointer. It that mean it print the address of the pointer?

Comment: It prints the address that the pointer contains, not the address of the pointer variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1, these are definitions of pointer `p`. One initializes the pointer to `NULL`, another leaves it uninitialized (if it is local variable in a function, and not global variable, global variables get initialized to 0 by default). Initializing with `NULL` can be good, or it can be bad, because compiler can warn you about use of uninitialized variables and help you find bugs. On the other hand compiler can't detect every possible use of uninitialized variable, so initializing to `NULL` is pretty much guaranteed to produce segmentation fault if used, which you can then catch and debug with a debugger very easily. Personally I'd go with always initializing when variable defined, with the correct value if possible (if initialization is too complex for single statement, add a helper function to get the value).

Question 2, `%p` prints the address value passed to `printf`. So `printf("%p", pointer);` gets passed *value* of variable `pointer` and it prints that, while `printf("%p", &pointer);` (note the extra `&` there) gets passed address of the variable `pointer`, and it prints that. Exact numeric format of `%p` is implementation defined, it might be printed just as a plain number.

Question 3 is about undefined behavior, because format string has more items than what you actually pass to `printf`. Short answer is, behavior is undefined, there is no "why". Longer answer is, run the application with machine code debugger and trace the execution in disassembly view to see what actually happens, to see why. Note that results may be different on different runs, and behavior may be different under debugger and running normally, because memory may have different byte values in different runs for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

1) The first is an initialization (to `NULL` in this case) the second is only a declaration of `p` as a pointer to `int`, no initial value is assigned to `p` in this case. You should always prefer an initialization to prevent undefined behavior.

2) You should cast to `void*` when using `%p` to print out a pointer (beware that you are using it too many times in your format specifier). The memory address to which `p` points is printed.

Comment: Why do you recommend casting to `void*`? (this is a honest question; if there's a reason, I'd like to know too)

Comment: @hyde Because a `void*` is what the `%p` format specifier is expecting

Comment: After investigation, yeah seems nothing implicit happens to pointers when passed to varargs function, so casting to `void*` is the proper thing to do with `%p`.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
int *p = NULL
```

defines and initializes a pointer 'p' to NULL. This is the correct way to initialize pointers in order to get "Seg Fault" if you forget to assign a valid address to this pointer later.

```
int *p
```

Only defines a pointer "p" with an unknown address. If you forget to assign a valid value to this pointer before using it, then some compilers will notify you about this mistakes while some others will not and you may access a non-valid address and get a run time error or undefined behaviour of the program.

2) "%p" is printing the address where the pointer is points. Since the pointer holds an address, then "%p" prints this address.

```
printf("%p\t%p",s);
```

So the first "%p" will print the address where the pointer "s" points which is the address which stores the string "hello". However, note that you are using twice "%p" but you providing only one pointer to print its address !!
Most compilers will not scream about this cause it is effect-less; however try to avoid it.

Comment: "Most compilers will not scream about this cause it is effect-less" ... If your compiler does not scream warning for detectable `printf` etc format string mistakes like this, then you need to up the warning level! `-Wall -Wextra` is good start for *gcc* and *clang*. If your compiler is not able to warn about stuff like this, you should seriously consider switching compilers at least for development builds, or at least running a separate static analyzer. Furhtermore, it is dreaded Undefined Behavior, and you can't really rely on it being effectless.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken with another case.

Comment: This line will give you an error, the compiler will try to print the second "%p" and will not find any pointer to print so it will give an error, not warning!!

Comment: Compiler should not give an error, just a warning, because `printf` is varargs functions, and contents of the format string are not really handled by the compiler. Producing warning is just an extra feature of the compiler, separate from actually compiling, added because mistakes in format strings are so common.

Answer (score 0):

Answer1 :

```
int *p=NULL;
```

p is a pointer to a int variable initialized with NULL. Here NULL means pointer p is not pointing to any valid memory location.

```
int *p;
```

p is a pointer to a int variable. p in uninitialized. Reading uninitialized variables is Undefined Behavior. (one possibility if try to use is that it will throw a segmentation fault)

Answer2:

It prints content of pointer. I mean base address of string "hello"

Comment: I clearly explained the context like local variable. read carefully.

Comment: "This means that if you try to use (dereference) an **initialized** pointer you have Undefined Behavior." make a correction it should be "uninitialized"

Comment: @Bolov Changes incorporated .

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that in `*p = NULL`, NULL is a pre-defined and standard 'place' where the pointer points. 
Reading from Wikipedia,

```
The macro NULL is defined as an implementation-defined null pointer constant, 
which in C99 can be portably expressed as the integer value 0 
converted implicitly or explicitly to the type void*.
```

This means that the 'memory cell' called `p` contains the MACRO value of NULL.
If you just write `int *p`, you are naming the memory cell with the name `p` but this cell is empty.